# Error signing output with public key from file 'key.pfx' -- Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting following error in VS2015 when trying to compile a c# project that uses code signing. I didn't get this error in VS2013.

Also there is no information on this error anywhere.

Comment: Is it a click once application? How exactly are you signing, and what project type is it?

Comment: @vcsjones It's a c# project

Comment: I am using project properties dialog to set key file to the project for signing.

Comment: Also just to be verbose I do have `AssemblyKeyFile` attribute in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. Looking in to it.

Comment: @vcsjones thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: @patrick-nelson-msft can you please help?

Comment: Anyone???? Nobody else ran into this issue at all?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. You can open CommonAssemblyInfo.cs and remove the line `[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile(@"C:\KeyFile.snk")]` :)

Comment: Yes that'll fix the error but just fixing the error is not the goal. If I remove this then assembly won't be code signed.

Answer (score 3):

I had more or less the same issue with VS 2019 while building a project, but with a `.snk` file, for a project containing the source code from [datalust Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/tree/dev/src/Superpower) that I needed to evaluate and debug:
[image: Error signing output with public key from file '../../asset/Superpower.snk' -- File not found]

The `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` did not contain any line `[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile(@"....snk")]`

The solution was to **unselect "Sign the assembly"** in the properties of the project:
[image: VS project sign the assembly]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reexport your pfx and ensure that "Include all certificates" option is cleared to exclude full certificate chain which may cause some problems.

If it does not help use AssemblyKeyName("xxx") instead of AssemblyKeyFile. Command **sn.exe -i key.pfx xxx** should be executed at your build server or development machine first to install the key into CSP. (I guess your error message is caused just by AssemblyKeyFile attribute.)

Let me note that there is no need to use your trusted certificate (signed by some Certification Authority) for assembly (or strong name) signing. Strongly named assembly can be digitally signed for authentication/security purposes later.

So you may also avoid the problem if you generate a new key using Strong Name Tool:

sn -k keyPair.snk

and use your current .pfx only with  e.g. signtool.

Comment: I think you are not understanding the issue here, same works fine under VS 2013. This issue is specific to VS2015

Comment: I've encountered the same problem in VS2015 today - CS7027 Value does not fall within the expected range. Cease to use AssemblyKeyFile, use only project properties or AssemblyKeyName and I believe it will work :-) Or create special keyPair.snk... I suppose it is some of the less significant problems of VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

How to sign an assembly simplified (TLDR;)

You can do this if you want to keep code signing in place for the assembly:

1. On Visual Studio Menu View->Terminal
2. In terminal run the command "sn -k sgKey.snk". This creates sgKey.snk as your key pair.
3. Then on your project properties you can navigate to the Signing tab, then choose Sign the assembly, then choose strong key file, and then select the key file you generated.
4. Compile and run.

Docs for reference:

- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/sign-strong-name#:~:text=Create%20and%20sign%20an%20assembly%20with%20a%20strong,New%20and%20enter%20its%20name%20in%20...%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/sign-strong-name#:%7E:text=Create%20and%20sign%20an%20assembly%20with%20a%20strong,New%20and%20enter%20its%20name%20in%20...%20)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-public-private-key-pair
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool

As Microsoft states: Do not rely on strong names for security. They provide a unique identity only.

Answer (score -1):

For using sign don't create a password for the key.